# google cloud sql choking under heavy load

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, koa2

To start I thought I should give a bit of a background.

We have a https api that is running in nodejs with the koa2 framework to handle any incoming requests.
This is running on a Compute Engine with 2 vCPUs and 9GB memory.

This then connects to Cloud SQL via a private IP address to a Postgres v9.6 database.
This is running 4 vCPUs, 15GB memory and a 500GB ssd drive (currently we are at 259GB usage of space).

We have thousands of weather and soil monitoring stations post data to our GCE via FTP (I know, I am trying to get them to phase this out), which then uses a PHP script to read the data and pump that into the database.  This happens at intervals of every 15mins to every few hours.

We also now have a good 300 or so stations that push a json request to the api to ingest the data.  This happens every 2 hours, on the hour.
This is now where it gets tricky.

Every 2 hours the api runs like a dog, it's almost unusable.
Because of this, it is also causing the 300 stations to randomly timeout and not send data, and then the next cycle it attempts to upload 4h worth of data, which then again randomly times out, and thus the cycle repeats.

This end point does 2 things

1. authenticates the jwt token via the database
2. logs a Google Tasks job to run
   (the google tasks job picks up the payload and inserts that into the database (uses update or insert))

I have checked by running up to 4 clustered api server scripts over this period to no effect, so that leads me to think it isn't the api, but more the database.

We can replicate the issue by using the npm package `loadtest -c 50 --rps 200 http://localhost:9092/v3/integrations/inbound`

this gives us (this is our logs, not logs from loadtest)

```
[2020-07-07 22:00:42][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {6715ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:43][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {7633ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:44][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {8447ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:45][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {9519ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:46][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {10531ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:47][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {11530ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:48][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {11927ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:48][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {12704ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:49][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {13344ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:49][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {13694ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:50][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {14532ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:51][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {15620ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:00:52][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {16557ms}'
```

you can see here the response times are massive.  Removing the auth check drops that down a lot

```
[2020-07-07 22:08:13][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {82ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:27][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {59ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:27][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {160ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:27][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {100ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:27][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {157ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:27][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {171ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:28][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {189ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:28][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {329ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:28][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {264ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:28][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {396ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:29][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {313ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:29][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {449ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:30][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {457ms}'
[2020-07-07 22:08:30][INFO] '[POST][200] /v3/integrations/inbound {453ms}'
```

This doesn't fix the problem, as we need it to authenticate, and the api still gets hit at this time and is also slow still.

What I should also note is that on both the GCE and GSQL we are no way near topping out on any of the resources.

We are at a loss of what to do, can anyone help out, or have any suggestions?

thanks all

Comment: This can be caused by many different things. If you are still having the issue, I would suggest opening an issue tracker [1] so that the GCP support team can take a look at your logs and troubleshoot the issue. 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: yeah we are at a loss as to what is happening, I will go to google and see what they have to say and update this post